# Does self.<function> within a class always mean that this <function> was defined higher up the inheritance chain?

Tags: python, class

I am working with a bunch of code with many layers and multiple class `inheritance`.

I have come this class:

```
class Subparser(Parser): 
    def unpack_data(self,data,timestamp): 
        self.write_tse_full(header, message, capt)
```

And my question is, can we be 100% sure that the `write_tse_full()` function was defined in a parent/sibling class?

Or could it have been defined on its own in this `class Subparser()`? And if so, am I right in saying that `self` is assigned to it so that we can later on access it in child classes that inherit from this Subparser() class?

I am familiar with class inheritance, and generally understand how '`self`' operates, but this is a weird one as usually I've come across `self.<attribute_of_class>`.

I am also familiar with MRO in terms of class inheritance.

Thanks in advance!

One final thing- I tried to trace the `self.write_tse_full()` function up a few layers but couldn't find where it's base class is, hence my question about it being possibly defined in the Subparser class for the first time. And if I am wrong on this, is there a way to jump to where it was originally defined if I am wrong??

Comment: There are lots of places it could be defined, as you realize. It certainly could be defined in `Subparser`. It's unclear to me from your question, did you check the code for `Subparser`? Is it defined there?

Comment: Searching for the text `def write_tse_full(` across all the files is probably the best way to find everywhere it was defined, as long as they're not using any weird tricks.

Comment: Great thanks Dan. And yepp I tried looking in `Subparser` and even higher up but couldn't find it. 
I didn't think of grepping the function, let me try this.